# Teak flooring in the shower, good idea or bad?

Tags: flooring, shower

There is a trend to place teak flooring into the shower. What is the best way to accomplish this with minimal problems? Is there an advantage to having teak flooring in a shower, or is it just not a great idea no matter what type of wood is used to place it into a shower?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I obviously realize there must be a water resistant sub-floor. And until the kids are out of the house "one more thing to clean" was the perfect comment I needed to hear. If I go that route for the ascetics, I'll wait until it's just the husband and I to clean up after.

Answer (score 5):

The teak wood is not the actual floor of the shower it is just a layer on top of the waterproof substrait or tile.  There is no wood that has properties to form a shower subfloor - it holds too much water, expands and contracts too much, and rots.  Not to mention sanitary issues.

So can you put teak in a shower.  Sure.  You can stand on top of whatever you want as long as the underneath part is waterproof and drains.  However you are just adding another (major) thing to clean.

Comment: 100% agree. I would make it removable so the hair and soap can be cleaned out every now and then. +

Comment: +1 And teak inserts need spacing so water can easily drain to the real floor and outlet.